# Create CfnDBCluster in non-default VPC?

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a serverless aurora database with the AWS CDK (1.19.0). However, it will always be created in the default VPC of the region. If I specify a vpc_security_group_id cloudformation fails because the provided security group is in the vpc created in the same stack as the aurora db.

"*The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs.*"

Here is my code sample:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_rds as rds,
    aws_ec2 as ec2
)


class CdkAuroraStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # The code that defines your stack goes here
        vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "VPC")

        sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, "SecurityGroup",
            vpc = vpc,
            allow_all_outbound = True    
        )

        cluster = rds.CfnDBCluster(self, "AuroraDB",
            engine="aurora",
            engine_mode="serverless",
            master_username="admin",
            master_user_password="password",
            database_name="databasename",
            vpc_security_group_ids=[
                sg.security_group_id
            ]
        )
```

Do I miss something and it is possible to create the CfnDbCluster in a specific vpc or is this just not possible atm?

Thanks for any help and advice. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a DB subnet group and include only the subnets you want Amazon RDS to launch instances into. Amazon RDS creates a DB subnet group in default VPC if none is specified.

You can use `db_subnet_group_name` property to specify your subnets, however it is better to use high-level constructs. In this case, there is one called DatabaseCluster.

```
cluster = DatabaseCluster(
    scope=self, 
    id="AuroraDB",
    engine=DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA,
    master_user=rds.Login(
        username="admin",
        password="Do not put passwords in your CDK code directly"
    ),
    instance_props={
        "instance_type": ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL),
        "vpc_subnets": {
            "subnet_type": ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE
        },
        "vpc": vpc,
        "security_group": sg
    }
)
```

> Do not specify password attribute for your database, CDK assigns a Secrets Manager generated password by default.

Just to note that this construct is still experimental, that means there might be a breaking change in the future.

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately, my database cluster needs to be serverless, which is (afaik) only possible with the CfnDbCluster construct (correct me if I am wrong).  But I created a CfnDBSubnetGroup and passed it's name to `db_subnet_group_name` which put the db in the right vpc. thanks again, much appreciated!